# Why does springboot refresh the bean only once when I remove bean and add another bean?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I have a requirement to remove the corresponding Bean and then add another Bean, but I find that springboot only refreshes the injected Bean once

the springboot version is 2.1.5.RELEASE,JDK1.8

```java
    public class Users {
        String name;
        int age;
        String gender;

        public Users() {
        }
        public Users(String name, int age, String gender) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.gender = gender;
        }
    }
```

```java
    @Component
    public class UsersController implements ApplicationRunner {
         @Autowired(required = false)
    //     @Resource
         List<Users> users= Collections.emptyList();


        @Override
        public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
            System.out.println(users);
        }
    }
```

```java
    @RestController
    public class HelloController implements 
    BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {

        ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        DefaultListableBeanFactory defaultListableBeanFactory;

        Users users;

        int i=0;

        @RequestMapping("/hello1")
        public String index1() {
            return "hello";
        }
        @RequestMapping("/hello3")
        public Users index3() {
            UsersController controller = 
    applicationContext.getBean(UsersController.class);
            controller.run(null);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry 
    registry) throws BeansException {

        }

        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory 
    beanFactory) throws BeansException {
            defaultListableBeanFactory= (DefaultListableBeanFactory) 
    beanFactory;
            Users users=new Users("hello"+(i++),23,"fe");
            this.users=users;
            defaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(users.getName(),
                BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(Users.class, () -> 
    users).getRawBeanDefinition());

        }
        @EventListener
        public void onApplicationEvent(@NonNull EnvironmentChangeEvent 
    environmentChangeEvent) {
            System.out.println("before 
    remove："+applicationContext.getBean(Users.class));
            defaultListableBeanFactory.removeBeanDefinition(users.getName());
            Users users=new Users("hello"+(i++),23,"fe");
            this.users=users;
            defaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(users.getName(),
                    BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(Users.class, 
    () -> users).getRawBeanDefinition());

        System.out.println("after："+applicationContext.getBean(Users.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext 
    applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            this.applicationContext=applicationContext;
        }
    }
```

pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
             <version>1.18.8</version>
          </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

only bootstrap.yml:

```
     management:
      endpoints:
        web:
          exposure:
           include: '*'
      endpoint:
        health:
          show-details: always
```

when start the application it will output
 `[Users(name=hello0, age=23, gender=fe)]`,
and then visit the url by POST,
        `http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh`
it will output
        `before remove：Users(name=hello0, age=23, gender=fe)`
        `after：Users(name=hello1, age=23, gender=fe)`
then visit the url
        `http://localhost:8080/hello3`
output
        `[Users(name=hello1, age=23, gender=fe)]`
This is to be expected,if visit the url again
        `http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh`
output
        `before remove：Users(name=hello1, age=23, gender=fe)`
        `after：Users(name=hello2, age=23, gender=fe)`
This is also to be expected,but visit the url
        `http://localhost:8080/hello3`
we hope it output 
        `Users(name=hello2, age=23, gender=fe)`
but it output
        `Users(name=hello1, age=23, gender=fe)`

The output message is not what we expected.
If change @Autowired to @Resource in class UsersController, it should be normal.But it maybe null in real environment,the application will run fail if use @Resource
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: or how to let @Resource to allow null values

Answer (score 0):

@Resource
@Lazy
can star application properly.But it may cause error like
`ERROR [main]  com.Users - No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<com.Users>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=), @org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy(value=true)}`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this part of the documentation in order to refresh your beans at runtime: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#refresh-scope